# Visual Studio ItemTemplate Shared Parameters

Tags: itemtemplate, visual-studio-templates

I am able to create a vs template to add multiple items to a project; however, I have two project items that are related to each other.  I would like to get the generated `$rootid$` from one project item and replace a specific variable in the another item template with this newly generated `$rootid$`.  Anyone has idea on how to achieve that?  or can I do that?